Replace Text processer does not change the part which I need
I have a Replace Text processer and I need to change the part of the file content,
Let me give a example, these lines belongs the file that will be processed ;
030   111111 22222  333333                                                           22  CCC                                                  142412414                                           2222                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    11111                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       NA    
 001   2222222 333333  444444                                                                11  22222                                            1111111                                           2222               0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     FFFF     CCC                                     4121T                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                966

and as you can see there are two lines - the part that I need to change is last indexes of lines, If the 'NA' appears in last indexes replace with empty space ''
I tried with these positons but none of them worked - they deleted the indexes which are not 'NA' ;
SSS,$25,$3,$6,$8,0,$1,$13,,$15,,,$2,$4,$7,$10,$5,${'$12':equals('NA'):ifElse('', ${'$12'})} ,$20,$21,,,,

SSS,$25,$3,$6,$8,0,$1,$13,,$15,,,$2,$4,$7,$10,$5,${'$12'.replaceAll('NA', '')},$20,$21,,,,

$12 group is represents the last indexes.
Thanks in advance

Can you please post your whole ReplaceText config? You have obviously more to do, then only replace 'NA's if they are the last text in a line.

Thanks for your interest, I solved it with another Replace text processor.

I added another Replace text processor and it solved my problem
